# Making a new model vs. reusing an old model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a feedback form where `User`'s can leave `Suggestions`. One type of `Suggestion` is a `Tag` definition. This is the only type of `Suggestion` that has a target of sorts. It would in theory point to one tag. Other suggestions are just simply text and don't refer to any specific object.

Is it better practice to have a separate model for `Tag` definition submissions, or is it better practice to combine the models together, and when a `Tag` definition submitted, I would just fill in a `tag_id`. And if it's null, I can ignore it.

I wasn't sure what the Rails (or any development) best practice is. Creating new models for 1 purpose vs. forcing models to fit inside others.

EDIT:

Additionally, I have an "Abuse" model, which is polymorphic and takes an object, but I assume using that would be very inaccurate for a "definition submission."?

Comment: When a tag definition arrives for Suggestion, you have to store that tag or point to a tag? Either way, if you store a tag_id, it will still point to a `Tag` object? What did you mean by 'forcing models to fit inside others'.

Comment: I mean, the suggestion model currently just sort of stands on its own. It does not point yo an object, it's just the suggestion text. So by adding the tag_id field, I'm tweaking the model to actually fit two different kinds of objects. I didn't know if this practice would be considered thrifty by combining similar models into one, or if it was more forcing two different objects to be served by one model.

Comment: I am pointing out the same. See, if you add `tag_id`, that means it is a foreign key of `Tag` model. You still have two different models.

Comment: Right. What I mean, is that the current `Suggestion` model does not point to anything. There is no foreign key (other than the `User` who submits it.) Adding the tag_id as a foreign key would only be used when submitting a `Tag` definition. Otherwise it will always be null. I didn't know if it was more correct to just make a new model for `Definitions` and leave the `Suggestion` model as is. Or maybe, adding the `tag_id` would be totally fine and I am overcomplicating it. Mainly, I was asking about best practices: creating new models vs. consolidating models.

Comment: I have another example, people can report abuse on a program or a user. So it's a model with details and a polymorphic object. Would it better to use tag definitions in that class, and the class could just be called "comments" the with a flag or string signifying definition or abuse ? In other words, do you try to reuse and recycle models or always make a new one even if the attributes are all the same, but the purpose they serve is different.